# MySQL GROUP BY while keeping certain rows by column content

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

There is table with duplicated rows. See rows 1 and 2:

```
id   full_name    email           status   active
1    John Doe     john@mail.com   ok       1
2    John Doe     john@mail.com   null     1
3    Ricky Duke   rick@mail.com   null     1
4    Jane Doe     jane@mail.com   block    1
```

I need to select distinct rows, not randomly - one distinct row, but the one that has a **'status' NOT NULL**.

My query is:

```
SELECT full_name, email
FROM `subscribers`
WHERE active = 1 AND (status = 'ok' OR status IS NULL)
GROUP BY email
```

That query selects distinct rows randomly, without prioritizing 'status' field.

How can i prioritize selection of distinct rows, that has a **'status' NOT NULL**, and select ones with NULL only in case there is no rows with 'ok' status is present?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by email order by (status is not null) desc) as seqnum
      from subscribers s
      where active = 1
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter with a correlated subquery that does conditional ordering, and gives a lowest priority to `null` statuses:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.id = (
    select id
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.full_name = t.full_name
        and t1.email = t.email
        and t1.active = t.active
    order by status is null, status  
    limit 1
)
```

This defines duplicats as records that have the same `full_name`, `email` and `active`. You might want to adapt that to your actual definition of duplicates.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ed0cd16a3ec30ea5b946b5bf285384b5)**:

```
id | full_name  | email         | status | active
-: | :--------- | :------------ | :----- | :-----
 1 | John Doe   | john@mail.com | ok     | 1     
 3 | Ricky Duke | rick@mail.com | null   | 1     
 4 | Jane Doe   | jane@mail.com | block  | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT full_name, email
FROM `subscribers`
WHERE active = 1 AND status IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY email) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT full_name, email
FROM `subscribers`
WHERE active = 1 AND status IS NULL AND
email not in (SELECT distinct email
FROM `subscribers` 
WHERE active = 1 AND status IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY email);
```